# Multiple select tag using *ngfor Changing first select tag value affects other select tag

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, datatable

```html
      <table id="DataTable" border="1" ALIGN="center">
     <tr ALIGN="center">
      <th>name</th>
      <th>address</th>
      <th>number</th>
      <th>type</th>
     </tr>
     <tr class="tcat" *ngFor="let item of Tdata;  let i = index;">
      <td class="name">{{item.name}}</td>
      <td class="address">{{item.address}}</td>
      <td class="number">{{item.number}}</td>
      <td class="type" ALIGN="center"
       *ngIf="!item.type || item.type == null || item.type == 'undefined'">
       <select (click)="jsFunction();">
             <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
            <option *ngFor="let currentData of dropdata"> 
              {{currentData.type}}</option>
          </select>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>`
```

**.ts file**

```
    dropdata:any;
  Tdata = [
    { name: "xyz", address: "abc", number: 12345, type: null },
    { name: "xyz1", address: "abc1", number: 78900, type: null },
    { name: "xyz2", address: "abc2", number: 7400, type: null }
  ];
  selecttedDropData = {};

  jsFunction() {
    // called second api;
    this.dropdata = [
      { number: "12345", type: "customer" },
      { number: "12345", type: "dealer" },
      { number: "12345", type: "client" },
      { number: "12345", type: "master" }
    ];

  }
```

1. On page load i have displayed a table and in column type i have added
   a drop-down.
2. On click each drop-down i am calling a `API` and getting a data to fill option.
3. The only problem is when I clicked on first drop-down or any other drop-down and select any option and after that, I select second or any other drop-down so the all selected drop-down value change and so.

Couldn't find any useful and correct answer. Please help me.

Thank you so much.

Comment: When you change the option, would you need to affect already selected dropdown by the fetched data?

Comment: And the second api fetches different values, right?

Comment: every dropdown on click there is a API call. and the second API fetches different value every time. there is multiple dropdown in table and when i select a dropdown all the selected dropdown changes

Comment: If my ans helps you, pleaee upvote and click tick to help people who seek this kind of question

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same reference for your bind data.

One solution could be to declare the dropData as an array of size the size of your array.

```
this.dropData = new Array(this.Tdata.length);
```

Then use the respective table for values. You need to make a clone of each with something like this (included in the stackblitz). I chose a shallow copy with the spread operator in this case `[...this.data]`

```
 jsFunction(event, i) {
    if (this.dropdata[i] == null || this.dropdata[i].length < 1) {
      this.dropdata[i] = [...this.data];
    }
  }
```

Then in the html

```
*ngFor="let currentData of this.dropData[index]"
```

[Demo Here - StackOverflow](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzr7ye)

My advice to you is that you use something like material select. You will notice that you need to click three times on the dropdown list to open if you remove the (this.dropdata[i] || data). This is because it is very difficult add options while the select is open. So first click opens it empty, second click closes it and the third opens it with the new data.

This is another problem that can be fixed but I don't think it's in the scope of the question.

You'll keep bumping to these. Others like [material select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) have already solved these problems.

Comment: can you share a demo.

Comment: Will do, just not right now as I have no available PC

Comment: thank you for guidance. so now I am using mat-table and for dropdown mat-select but the thing is when I select 1st or any other dropdown I am calling an API and getting a value that I showed in option for example 1,2,3 and I choose 2. note that every dropdown option data is different. so if I click on 2nd or any other dropdown the same API called but the getting value might change for example 4,5,6 so when the 4,5,6 load in option the 1st dropdown selected value change to 5.  the same goes to other dropdowns. i thing its because of the same this.dropData scope to all dropdowns

Comment: Did you follow the Demo guide? I am using a different array of values for each of the dropdowns and a different selected value.

Comment: yes, it works but another problem occurs. in mat-table if I select dropdown value and jump to next page I mean using pagination and come to that page again the selected dropdown value doesn't stay there on that dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
selecttedDropData = {};


  jsFunction(num) {
    // called second api;
    let dropData = [
      { number: "12345", type: "customer" },
      { number: "12345", type: "dealer" },
      { number: "12345", type: "client" },
      { number: "12345", type: "master" }
    ];
    this.selecttedDropData[num] = dropData;
  }
```

Template:

```
<option [value]="currentData.type" *ngFor="let currentData of selecttedDropData[item.name]"> 
        {{currentData.type}}
</option>
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdcfxo?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: In demo. only one option get selected in all dropdown

Comment: please note the value in let dropData is going to change for every dropdown. so if I clicked on 1st dropdown, for example, I am getting 1,2,3 data from API and I select 2 and after that, if I select 2nd or any other dropdown I will get different data for example 4,5,6 so 1st dropdown selected value change to 5 because the scope of let dropData value changed.

Answer (score 0):

Define an array to store second api call `selectedData=[];`. Actually I've done a small trick. Since we can't differentiate the `<select>` and `<option>`, tag when click. I used a variable `open` to know whether the select dropdown is open or not.

```
<select (blur)="closeSelect()" (click)="jsFunction(i);">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option [value]="currentData.type" *ngFor="let currentData of selectedData[i]">{{currentData.type}}</option>
</select>
```

if it's open and clicked, we can add it into array with the corresponding index.

```
jsFunction(i){
    // telling open = false / true
    this.open=!this.open;
    // called second api;
    let data=[
        {number: "1",
        type: "customer"},
        {number: "2",
        type: "dealer"},
        {number: "3",
        type: "client"},
        {number: "4",
        type: "master"},
    ]
    if(this.open)
        this.selectedData[i]=data;
}
```

When you click on value or outside `(blur)`, we make the `open = false`.

```
closeSelect(){
  this.open=false
}
```

Since no other answers are working, this can solve your problem.I also searched, but no luck. I will try to optimize it.

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-select-tag-with-dynamic-options)

Comment: please note the value in let data is going to change for every dropdown. so if I clicked on 1st dropdown, for example, I am getting 1,2,3 data from API and I select 2 and after that, if I select 2nd or any other dropdown I will get different data for example 4,5,6 so 1st dropdown selected value change to 5 because the scope of let data value changed.